# What are the different ways to do real time ingestion in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am using MarkLogic-10 and DHF5 in my project. I have a requirement to do real time ingestion and harmonization. My requirement is to do step1 & 2 harmonization if any changes in the document(delta load)

Answer (score 0):

See the information at https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.5/flows/about-flows.html about real time flows, which is new in DHF 5.5.